# C++ should a function be overloaded or if statement is enough?

Tags: c++, function, overloading

Good afternoon everyone.

I have a question regarding function overloading in C++.

There is a very big function in a class and my task is to make it more human readable and reduce it's complexity.

In that function, almost two similar code blocks exist. The only difference is in some parameters and couple of additional lines.

I want to create a function out of those blocks to avoid repeating, but how is it better to do? Should I overload that new function or add an if statement inside function so that if one parameter has this or that value, then those couple of additional lines should be executed as well?

What is the best approach?

The function looks like this

```
void f1(){
  //some code 
  {
  //some code block
  //some other line that belongs to this block
  //the code block continues
  }
  {
  //the same kind of code block
  //this line is completely different
  //the code block continues
  }

  //some code
}
```

So, I want to make a function out of the code blocks, but they are not completely the same and require some different operations performing right in the middle. 
Example:

```
void boo(){
  //code block
  //if(blah) execute this additional line
  //else this line
  //code block
}
```

or overloading

```
void boo(param1, param2){
   //code block
   //unique line
   //code block
}
 void boo(param1, param2, param3){
   //code block
   //unique line
   //code block
}
```

Comment: Is the function short enough to post it? If not, could you write up an example function that conveys the same idea?

Comment: well, it is quite long and I cannot post this code here.

Comment: This is opinion-based, but Since you want to reduce it's complexity and `IF` increase complexity. therefor i think it's better to overload than use if statement.

Comment: Just post the basic structure of the two functions if the code is very long.

Comment: You really have to give some insight about the function; each of us has his own interpretation of the general description. To me, it sounds like you have an if/else statement with almost the same code executing on each branch - in which case you simply have to execute the common code before the if/else statement.

Comment: if else would be a better approach since the size of the unique code is small. Also the param3 can have a default value which cannot be a possible agrument and can be used as the condition for if statement to determine which code has to be executed.

Comment: you need to try and avoid duplicating code - this is very error prone in the long run. The way you do that is you move that repeated piece of code in a function (which can be  an inline one) and call it wherever you need.

Comment: @PLAudet: Why do you suggest, that overloading a function doesn't increase the complexity, just like an `if` statement would? You add an additional path through your function either way. Whether the predicate is evaluated at compile-time or run-time does not make the least bit of a difference.

Comment: @IInspectable if you look at the code of the OP. Adding an overload will reduce the complexity of `boo()` (since it will be split in 2 different functions) but it will not reduce the complexity of the caller (`f1()`)

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand it, your situation is like this:

```
int FirstFunction(int parameter_1, bool parameter_2) {
  // first large section of code shared by both
  // line unique to FirstFunction
  // second large section of code shared by both
}

int SecondFunction(long parameter_1, Dawg parameter_2) {
  // line unique to SecondFunction
  // first large section of code shared by both
  // second large section of code shared by both
}
```

Is this accurate? If so, I would just take out each section of code that is identical (or very similar) between the two functions, put that section into its own function, and call it from both. Repeat until you have no duplicate code left:

```
void FirstSharedCode(/* parameters */) {
  // first large section of code shared by both
}

void SecondSharedCode(/* parameters */) {
  // second large section of code shared by both
}

int FirstFunction(int parameter_1, bool parameter_2) {
  FirstSharedCode(/* parameters */);
  // line unique to FirstFunction
  SecondSharedCode(/* parameters */);
}

int SecondFunction(long parameter_1, Dawg parameter_2) {
  // line unique to SecondFunction
  FirstSharedCode(/* parameters */);
  SecondSharedCode(/* parameters */);
}
```

Comment: oh, you have different names. wait a minute, I will make a proto

Comment: great you just removed the redundant code from the initial function and moved it into two separate one - it's a sure way to create bugs if that code has to change (very likely you will forget to update both code blocks)

Comment: @Pandrei I'm sorry? I don't understand what you're trying to say. The whole point of my answer was to take duplicated sections of code and separate them into their own functions, thus *reducing* duplication and *eliminating* the need to update both code blocks.

Comment: @RedRoboHood well your answer suggest that you are creating two new functions each one executing ' // first large section of code shared by both '. Which is exactly the redundancy I was pointing out. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Pandrei No; as stated in my answer, that code block is the asker's situation as I understand it, not my proposed solution. I'll update my answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
void boo(param1, param2){
    //code block
    //unique line
    //code block
}
void boo(param1, param2, param3){
    //code block
    //unique line
    //code block
}
```

into

```
void baa() {
    // code block1
}

void bee() {
    // code block2
}

void boo(param1, param2){
    baa();
    //unique line
    bee();
}
void boo(param1, param2, param3){
    baa();
    //unique line
    bee();
}
```

Or alternatively, you could pass in a lambda function for the unique line:

```
void boo(std::function<int()> unique) {
    // code block
    int bleh = unique();
    // code block
}
```

and just call as such:

```
boo([]() { return 1; });
boo([]() { return 3; });
```

Comment: Oh yeah, lambda could be one of the possible solutions. But I still need to have the code as simple as possible.

Comment: @maksims what's not simple with lambdas ?

Answer (score 1):

From the question statement the initial complex function kind of looks like this:

```
void f1(){
  //some code 
  {
     { <common_code_block_0> }
     <unique_code>
     { <common_code_block_1> }
  }
  {
     { <common_code_block_0> }
     <unique_code>
     { <common_code_block_1> }
  }

  //some code
}
```

There are two common code blocks which are repeated. These need to be isolated to reduce complexity and the likelihood of future bugs. Jut put each one of them in a separate function:

```
void function_0
{
   { <common_code_block_0> }
} 

void function_1
{
   { <common_code_block_1> }
}
```

Taking it one step further declare these two functions as inline to avoid any overhead from the function call.

```
 inline  void function_0();    
 inline  void function_1();
```

Since there is some unique code executed between the two common_code blocks on each branch, probably the there are parameters to be passed in/returned  to/from these new functions. So they probably look something like:

```
//parameters are I/O
inline void function_0(data_type* param1, data_type* param2, etc);
inline void function_1(data_type* param1, data_type* param2, etc);
```

And the initial f1() now looks like:

```
  void f1(){
  //some code 
  {
     function_0(&param1, &param2, etc);
     <unique_code>
     function_1(&param3, &param4, etc);
  }
  {
     function_0(&param1, &param2, etc);
     <unique_code>
     function_1(&param3, &param4, etc);
  }

  //some code
}
```

Comment: This one looks like very human readable and as simple as possible. I think I will proceed with something like this. Thank you

Comment: `inline` is not doing what you think it's doing. It tells the compiler that the function implementation is in the header, it doesn't say anything about inlining code. If you want to force inline you have to use your compiler attributes.

Comment: inline is not guaranteed by the compiler; I did not go into too much detail about that because it's not the point here.

Comment: Since it's not the point of the question (and you got it wrong, anyway), why not remove the useless `inline` mayhem?